# How to get columns category name on hover in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Im trying to get the category name of the columns when im hovering but cant to find the property in the highcharts docs.
I tried to see whats under the properties when im hovering over a column but still cant get the name

[image]

```
`cant past fiddle`http://jsfiddle.net/puw107xw/1/
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It is not clear to me exactly what you would like when you hover, that said, you should be able to find it here: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information about category is kept in the point object (not series):

```
   plotOptions: {
    column: {
      (...)
      point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver: function() {
            console.log(this.category)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tbtac5m9/

Comment: Thank you for your help.